# WorkManager is not initialized properly

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using work manager in my application and with the latest library

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
```

In the manifest

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

Application class

```
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .build()

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    WorkManager.initialize(this, Configuration.Builder().build())
}
}
```

I have added the initialization in application class. And yet I still face this erro

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan reinstalling the app worked out for us during development phase. And we didn't got this issue on play store builds

Comment: I am getting this error in oneSignal SDK integration can you help with this ? 
also I have reinstalled app but its not working

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan I don't see work manager being used in OneSignal SDK. Try downgrading SDK version. Are you using work manager in your application. If not and still you are seeing this error then it's SDK issue report to them.

Comment: Our app is using WorkManager intensively. We get this kind of error sometimes, in BroadcastReceiver scheduled by AlarmManager. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'

implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
```

Add this in Manifest inside

```
  <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

in Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class SAPWizardApplication: Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
    return Configuration.Builder()
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
}
}
```

Comment: Hi can you help me with this error. I try above solution but it cuasing error in my viewmodel class

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.classon.parentapp, PID: 10054
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly. You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(WorkManagerImpl.java:173)
at androidx.work.WorkManager.getInstance(WorkManager.java:184)
at